# Swift - Initialised properties from function return

Tags: function, swift, properties, declaration

I have a public function in another swift file that has return values. I want these return values to be initialised into properties in ViewController2.

**Public Function**

```
public func calculateBoundary (inout f:[Float], s:[Float], n:NSInteger) -> (forceBound1:Float, forceBound2: Float, displacement:[Float])
```

**ViewController2**

I want initialised 3 properties from the return values of *calculateBoundary* function, in ViewController2 class here.

```
    class ViewController2: UIViewController , UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

   // Values (f,s,n) are values that user input from another ViewController and then pass to this ViewController2.

// I'll then call the function _calcuateBoundary_ here, which passes the values (f,s,n) and then to calculate the return values here. 

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call your `calculateBoundary()` method in the initializer for your `ViewController2`.  Here is a sketch:

```
  // public function - in any file
  func ret3 () -> (b1:Float, b2:Float, b3:Float) { 
      return (1, 2, 3) 
  } 

 // your `ViewController2`
 class VC2 { 
   var b1 : Float 
   var b2 : Float 
   var b3 : Float 
   init () { 
     (b1, b2, b3) = ret3()
   } 
 }
```

And here it is in action:

```
> var vc2 = VC2()
vc2: VC2 = {
  b1 = 1
  b2 = 2
  b3 = 3
}
```

Comment: I don't understand line10 _vc1: VC1 = {}_ what does it do?

Comment: Let's say my public function is in another file and is not inside any class. How does the answer differs?

Comment: The output is from the Swift REPL.  Line 10 is where I create an instance of `VC1`.  But, I missed your statement about a 'public function' - I updated my answer.

Comment: Error of _Expression resolves to an unused i-value_ for b1,b2,b3. For my public function to return the values for (b1,b2,b3), the function has to take in (f,s,n) ,which user has to input the values for (f,s,n) in order for the function to do it's calculation. I have the error because the user program has not take in values for (f,s,n) yet.

Comment: Is it because of this, that's why this solution doesn't work for me? I hope you understand so far...

Answer (score 0):

```
var forceB1 : Float = 0.0
var forceB2 : Float = 0.0
var springD : [Float] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {

(forceB1,forceB2,springD) = calculateBoundary(&f1View2,f2View2, springDView2)

}
```

Comment: While this code is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how the code solves the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if the code ever stops working (due to an unrelated change) and users need to understand how it previously worked.